# Triangle Inequality for complex functions

Tags: complex-analysis

If $z$ is st. $z=Re^{i\theta}, R > \sqrt2$ how do I show that:

|$z^2+2z+2$|$\geq R^2-2R-2$?

If I use the traingle inequality I get:

|$z^2+2z+2$|$\geq||z^2+2z|-2|$ but I can't proceed further

Comment: Try complete the square.

Answer (score 1):

$$|x+y+z|\geqslant |x+y |-|z| \geqslant |x|-|y|-|z|$$

Comment: Why it is not true? Thus we have $$|z^2 +2z +2 |\geqslant |z|^2 -2|z| -2 =R^2 -2R -2 .$$

Answer (score 0):

Using the triangle inequality a couple of times gives something a bit stronger.
Since $|z+1|+|-z|\ge1$ and $|z+1|+|-1|\ge|z|$, we have $|z+1|\ge|\,|z|-1\,|$, and therefore, $|z+1|^2\ge(|z|-1)^2$. Then
$$
\begin{align}
|(z+1)^2+1|
&\ge|z+1|^2-1\\
&\ge(|z|-1)^2-1\\
&=|z|^2-2|z|
\end{align}
$$
Thus,
$$
|(z+1)^2+1|\ge R^2-2R
$$